# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger

Tags: android

Я использую следующие зависимости:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0' 
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'   
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.9.0' 
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile "net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.5.1"
}
```

и при сборке проекта получаю ошибку:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   Process: com.icard.rest, PID: 13758
>                                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger
>                                                                       at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:116)
>                                                                       at com.comp.model.App.onCreate(App.java:30)
>                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4464)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
>                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Предполагаю, что какие-то из этих библиотек несовместимы... Но как это исправить?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я использовала `multiDexEnabled true`, но не подключила библиотеку для мультидекса:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

После подключения этой библиотеки и изменения кода класса приложения:

```
App extends Application
```

на

```
App extends MultiDexApplication
```

проблема исчезла.